# I am trying to mock Http.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, nunit, moq

We are using C#, WebAPI, Moq and Nunit. I have a `MarketingController` which is an API controller. I need to mock

```
HTTPContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage
```

I tried these approaches:

In my

```
[TestInitialize]
Setup()
{
    MockHttpContextBase = new Mock<HttpContextBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);
    MockHttpSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>(MockBehavior.Loose);

    var mockHttpContext = new MockHttpContext();
    _marketingController = new MarketingController
            {
                ControllerContext = new HttpControllerContext()
                //{
                //    HttpContext = mockHttpContext.HttpContext.Object
                //}
            };

    var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
    context.SetupGet(e => e.Request).Returns(request.Object);

    var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", 
             new SessionStateItemCollection(),                                                   
             new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 10, true,
             HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
             SessionStateMode.InProc, false);

    SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);

    HttpContext.Current = httpContext;
    HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("MS_HttpRequestMessage", "HelloMan"); 
}
```

In the actual code, I have a method to retrieve `currentItems` from the `HttpContext`.

```
protected HttpSessionStateBase GetMysessforServ()
{
    var request = HttpContext.Current.Items[MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as   HttpRequestMessage;

    if (request == null)
        return null;

    var httpcontent = (HttpContextWraper)request.Properties[""]
    ....        
    ....
    ....
    ....
    return httpContext.session
}
```

Here my unit test are failing because the mock is getting executed and the call for `HTTPContext.Current.Items["MS_HttpRequestMessage"] as HttpRequestMessage` is always returning null.

I am also mocking `HttpContext` for other controller and it works fine but this one is api controller

Please advise

Comment: are you sure if some of your vars - httpRequest or httpResponse is not null? Where do you get the values for those objects?

Comment: I am passing values for httprequest and httpResponse as below 
           var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
            var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
            var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);